# What PayPal data should I save in my database for future use?

Tags: mysql, database, paypal

You know how in some sites you can save a payment method like a credit card that you can use later without having to fill the needed fields again?

I've never used PayPal and couldn't seem to be able to find what data is usually filled when making a purchase.

```
CREATE TABLE VisaPayment (
    idVisaPayment int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    idUser int NOT NULL,
    cardNumber int NOT NULL,
    cardCVCNumber int NOT NULL,
    cardExpirationDate int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idVisaPayment),
    FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES Users(idUser),
);
```

If the above is my table for storing Visa card data, what attributes should I save for PayPal?

I found [What kind of data obtained from a paypal transaction I should store inside my local database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404358/what-kind-of-data-obtained-from-a-paypal-transaction-i-should-store-inside-my-lo) and [Which API will allow me to save PayPal as a reusable payment type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888068/which-api-will-allow-me-to-save-paypal-as-a-reusable-payment-type), but they're not what I'm looking for. The case in the first link is for **after a purchase has been made** and the latter requires something called a *reference transaction*, which I cannot (nor wish to) obtain because I don't have a business.

This is for a project database.

So for now, all I have is the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE PaypalPayment (
    idPaypalPayment int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    idUser int NOT NULL,
    <???>
    PRIMARY KEY (idPaypalPayment),
    FOREIGN KEY (idUser) REFERENCES Users(idUser),
);
```

Comment: That depends on what you need. But out of curiosity: which security protections are in place to avoid credit card data to be stolen? You don't have a business, but you store all sensitive data of a credit card? Not to ask why the expire data is an integer (which it obviously is not)

Comment: Card numbers are strings, not integers. I would leave this kind of thing to someone who was more qualified; storing this information in this way would probably end badly for someone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's probably immoral and possibly illegal

Comment: @NicoHaase I haven't gotten to choosing and implementing security protection at the moment. Although, I'll probably just encrypt the data and then store it as an array of bytes (as a varchar maybe). As for the expiration date, it could be stored as an `int`, 4 numbers and then when shown in the UI, simply add a `/` after the first two numbers. I'm not going to store **actual** credit card data, unless `0000 0000 0000 0000` is a real one who's CVC is `000` and expiration date is `00 / 00`.

Comment: I don't get that: why does your table for `VisaPayment` contain columns for credit card number and expiration date, when you don't store such data?

Comment: @NicoHaase I wanted to store fake data in my pet project's database so I can just select it from a list so I don't have to write new ones everytime I want to test something, but I guess that's "immoral and illegal" according to Mr.Strawberry ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: As you haven't told before that this is part of a "pet project", others had to assume the worst. There have been people doing this for real projects, and the implications have been worse than bad

Comment: @NicoHaase And I assumed that "This is for a project database." was enough for people to not assume I'm dumb enough to store real data as sensitive as this one in my own database. Oh well... live and learn I guess.

Comment: That depends on your type of project :) I'm working everyday on "project databases", as a "project" is a common term for applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes on storing cards:

1. If you are storing a real card number, it needs to be securely encrypted. There are strict Payment Card Industry (PCI) guidelines on this, and you need to follow a lengthy questionnaire ([SAQ-"D"](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/completing_self_assessment)) to be compliant if you really are storing ~16 digit numbers.
2. You are not allowed to store a CVC/CVV number, *ever*. Under absolutely no circumstances. It is the kind of information that needs to be *immediately* forgotten after it is inputted and transmitted (anything else is a complete violation of card processing rules)

---

Regarding a record of a successful PayPal transaction:

1. This is very simple, there will be a completed  PayPal capture or transaction ID, which is 17 alphanumeric capitals. It is not the same as a v2/checkout/orders ID, which can have the same 17 alphanumeric format but is only used during the checkout approval process.  So, after a PayPal order is captured, there will be a deeper payment object in the capture response with a new id that is the actual transaction ID.  This new id from the capture response is what should be persistently stored and used for accounting purposes, and can be reconciled with reports in the receiving [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) account.
2. Note that the transaction ID in the receiving PayPal account, and the transaction ID that the payer will see in their sending PayPal account, are two different transaction IDs, so do not display the above mentioned transaction ID to the buyer. Only display your own invoice ID, which should be unique and which you can pass along as part of the PayPal transaction when you set it up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I just won't store anything anywhere then.

Comment: Well do store your PayPal transaction IDs forever, and you can also store other IDs like the Order ID and any 'debug_id' in the response for however long might be useful (perhaps a month).  And if you are processing credit cards, there should be IDs in the response for you to store, like a transaction ID.